# Como pegar nome do diretório atual no PHP

Tags: php

Procurei no Google e aqui no SOpt, porém não achei nenhum site, ou pergunta aqui que respondesse esta pergunta.

**Exemplo:**

Estou na página `index.php` que está em `/5/index.php`, então deve ser capturado apenas o **5**.

Como imprimir isto na página?

> Qual a forma mais simples e prática de pegar o **nome do diretório** em **PHP** ?

Pergunta bem simples, porém não encontrei nenhum método útil pra pegar esta informação. :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O método para saber a diretoria actual é [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

> *"gets the current working directory"*

Tens mais alternativas,

- podes usar o [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) em combinação com [`__FILE__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) que dá a diretoria do ficheiro em que estás.
- podes usar o [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) em combinação com o [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) que vai dar o nome da diretoria em que estás.

Um exemplo no [PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rtee-kijk) seria assim:

```
echo getcwd().'<br>';
echo dirname(__FILE__).'<br>';
echo basename(__DIR__).'<br>';
```

que dá:

```
/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main
/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main
main
```

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo de utilização? :P

Comment: @AlexandreLopes juntei exemplo

Comment: Que resposta linda! Kkkk, ficou perfeito! Então é isso `basename(__DIR__)`, muito obrigado @Sergio me ajudando sempree! :P

Answer (score -4):

echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);